# C# Multithreading Loop Datatable

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable

I have a `datatable` with `1000 records`. Each row has a column with a link.I will loop the `datatable` and fetch record from the website using the link in the `datatable`. The code is working fine , but this is taking too much time to retrieve the records. So I need to pass it in multiple threads and fetch records and add all the records to a single `datatable`. I an using `C# , Visual studio 2015`.

How can we do using `threading C#`, Any help  appreciated.

Existing code is as below.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                String years = String.Empty;


                dt.Rows[i]["Details"] = GetWebText(dt.Rows[i]["link"].ToString());

            }



    private String GetWebText(String url)
        {
            var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
          string text= html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));

return text;
        }
```

Comment: Do you know about the Task Parallel Library? It is better if you use an abstraction instead of Threads directly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you in a console application or UI based?

Comment: @strongbutgood it is a console c#

Comment: @user1554650 check my modification using `Task.WaitAll` for Console, that will surely work, even `Task.WhenAll` with `ConfigureAwait(false)` works for me, when you say its handing please first ensure synchronous operation works as expected before shifting to Async version

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run in to issues here with the thread-safety of write operations with data tables. So you need to ensure that the operations that you perform are separated nice.

The good thing is that you are actually doing three distinct steps and you can easily break them apart and parallelize the slow part while keeping it thread-safe.

Here's what your code is doing:

```
var url = dt.Rows[i]["link"].ToString();
var webText = GetWebText(url);
dt.Rows[i]["Details"] = webText;
```

Let's process the data in these three steps, but only parallize the `GetWebText` part.

This is how:

```
var data =
    dt
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => new { Row = r, Url = r["link"].ToString() })
        .AsParallel()
        // This `Select` is the only part run in parallel
        .Select(x => new { x.Row, WebText = GetWebText(x.Url) })
        .ToArray();

foreach (var datum in data)
{
    datum.Row["Details"] = datum.WebText;
}
```

Comment: Though it does assign the result back to `DataTable` in an ordered manner in a parallel call, but using `PLinq` where `Async-Await` is the best option is surely a bad idea, Invoking threads for remote call.
 
Nonetheless I don't down-vote on drop of pin.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj you stated in your answer that a console app shouldn't use async/await. Doesn't async/await spawn new threads if required also?

Comment: @strongbutgood, No there's no thread in Async-Await, please check http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @MrinalKamboj that is a good blog to reference, perhaps you could put that information into your answer to provide context and better explain why your answer is actually the best option.

Comment: @strongbutgood done but you know working on Async-Await better be aware of Stephen Cleary's blog and Cookbook, they are kind of authority for modern day concurrency, explains nuances very well.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - There's nothing that makes `async`/`await` the "best" option. Why do you say that?

Comment: @Enigmativity what does the invoked thread pool thread do post IO call dispatch, beside waiting and wasting allocated resources. Neither There's computation for thread to be utilized, nor the thread can be freed to the pool as its in wait mode for the call to return

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Enigmativity, please refer to any expert that you may know on the topic to verify the point specified, I am pretty sure about difference between Parallel / PLinq and Async-Await

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - My tests so far are showing virtually identical performance with `async`/`await` and `AsParallel`.

Comment: @Enigmativity current day systems are good enough to handle multiple threads, even processor utilization remains low, with all the processes. Same operation when tried in the Enterprise setup would reflect the difference in  the concurrency strategies discussed.

Answer (score -1):

Blocking Collections can solve the problem:

```
Blocking<string> links= new BlockingCollection<string>();\\ using System.Collections.Concurrent;
Blocking<string> results= new BlockingCollection<string>();

public static void main()
{
//get your datatable
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
        ThreadStart t = new ThreadStart(threads);
      Thread th = new Thread(t);
        th.Start();
        }
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
        links.add(dt.Rows[i]["link"].ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           dt.Rows[i]["Details"] = results.Take();
          }
}
public void threads()
{
while(true)
 {
  string url= Links.take();//block if links is empty
  var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  string text= html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));
  results.add(text);//add result to the other queue
 }
}
```

Comment: Starting so many threads will kill the system, its not about thread safety, but using the correct mechanism to introduce concurrency, like `Async-Await`